# when I tried to add a category in my Cpanel I get this error 'Field 'path' doesn't have a default value'

Tags: php, cpanel

```
SET SQL_MODE = "NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";
SET time_zone = "+00:00";

CREATE TABLE `tbl_admin` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `username` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `password` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `image` varchar(255) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO `tbl_admin` (`id`, `username`, `password`, `email`, `image`) 
VALUES (1, 'admin', 'admin', 'nemosofts@gmail.com', 'profile.png');

CREATE TABLE `tbl_banner` (
  `bid` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `banner_title` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `banner_sort_info` varchar(500) NOT NULL,
  `banner_image` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `banner_songs` text NOT NULL,
  `status` int(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1'
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE `tbl_category` (
  `cid` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `category_name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `category_image` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `path` varchar(255) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE `tbl_live` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `image` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `url` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `total_views` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `video_type` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `cat_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `status` int(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1'
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE `tbl_settings` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `app_name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `app_logo` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `onesignal_app_id` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `onesignal_rest_key` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `publisher_id` varchar(500) NOT NULL,
  `interstital_ad` varchar(500) NOT NULL,
  `interstital_ad_id` varchar(500) NOT NULL,
  `interstital_ad_click` varchar(500) NOT NULL,
  `banner_ad` varchar(500) NOT NULL,
  `banner_ad_id` varchar(500) NOT NULL,
  `facebook_interstital_ad` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `facebook_interstital_ad_id` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `facebook_interstital_ad_click` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `facebook_banner_ad` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `facebook_banner_ad_id` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `facebook_native_ad` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `facebook_native_ad_id` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `facebook_native_ad_click` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `admob_nathive_ad` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `admob_native_ad_id` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `admob_native_ad_click` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `banner_ad_dialog` varchar(500) NOT NULL,
  `company` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `website` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `contact` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `purchase_code` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `nemosofts_key` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `package_name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `subscription_id` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `merchant_key` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `subscription_days` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `in_app` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `status` int(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1'
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO `tbl_settings` (
    `id`, `app_name`, `app_logo`, `onesignal_app_id`, `onesignal_rest_key`,
    `publisher_id`, `interstital_ad`, `interstital_ad_id`, `interstital_ad_click`,
    `banner_ad`, `banner_ad_id`, `facebook_interstital_ad`, 
    `facebook_interstital_ad_id`, `facebook_interstital_ad_click`, 
    `facebook_banner_ad`, `facebook_banner_ad_id`, `facebook_native_ad`, 
    `facebook_native_ad_id`, `facebook_native_ad_click`, 
    `admob_nathive_ad`, `admob_native_ad_id`, `admob_native_ad_click`, 
    `banner_ad_dialog`, `company`, `email`, `website`, `contact`, 
    `purchase_code`, `nemosofts_key`, `package_name`, `subscription_id`,
    `merchant_key`, `subscription_days`, `in_app`, `status`
) VALUES (
    1, 'Android Live TV', 'app_icon.png', 'xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx',
    'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx', 'ca-app-pub-3940256099942544',
   'true', 'ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/1033173712', '10', 'true', 
   'ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111', 'false', '', '10', 'false',
   '', 'false', '', '10', 'true', 'ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/2247696110',
   '6', 'false', 'nemosofts', 'thivakaran829@gmail.com',
   'https://www.nemosoftscom/', '+00 020456089',
   'xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx', '7sbfm9qa2t-e6rzmjvrwm-bc24d9ynew',
   'nemosofts.live.tv.app.new', 'onlinetv1234', '02587753396168028277', 
   '30', 'false', 0
);

CREATE TABLE `tbl_users` (
  `id` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(60) NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(70) NOT NULL,
  `password` text NOT NULL,
  `phone` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `status` int(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1'
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

ALTER TABLE `tbl_admin` ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`);

ALTER TABLE `tbl_banner` ADD PRIMARY KEY (`bid`);

ALTER TABLE `tbl_category` ADD PRIMARY KEY (`cid`);

ALTER TABLE `tbl_live` ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`);

ALTER TABLE `tbl_settings` ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`);

ALTER TABLE `tbl_users` ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`);

ALTER TABLE `tbl_admin` MODIFY `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=2;

ALTER TABLE `tbl_banner` MODIFY `bid` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;

ALTER TABLE `tbl_category` MODIFY `cid` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;

ALTER TABLE `tbl_live` MODIFY `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;

ALTER TABLE `tbl_settings` MODIFY `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=2;

ALTER TABLE `tbl_users` MODIFY `id` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;
```

Comment: You don't show the `tbl_category` insert, but the column definition has `\`path\` varchar(255) NOT NULL` which does not have a default, so `path` must not be provided in the insert? To have a default value, need to add a `DEFAULT` in the definition, such as: `\`path\` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT ''` to avoid supplying the value when not necessary.

Comment: can you tell me what to do please because I just buy this code and I don't have any knowledge about programming thank you

Comment: I just gave you the example in the previous comment. (for that one column) Of course, with the insert, you can simply add `''` to set the path to _something_ instead, and do nothing to change the column.

Comment: Did the suggestion in my second comment help, to simply set the path to `''`, without having to make any table-level changes?

Comment: if you mean like this    `category_name` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT'', didn't work

Comment: Should be a space after the `T` ... I updated my comment yesterday for another thing you can do without changing the table definition.

Comment: still didn't wor     `category_name` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',

Comment: What database and version do you have?  You can query `SELECT version();` to check

Comment: I don't have SQL installed on the laptop I have only notepad++

Comment: That's ok, are you using MySQL or MariaDB ?

Comment: i don't know what are you talking about because i already told you that i don't have any knowledge about programming i just buy this code but if want i can give you access to my cpanel and send you db to see if you don't mind

Comment: You don't have to know about programming, but I would think that cpanel, or your host, would show a list of applications that you have installed?

Comment: look what i found Server: Localhost via UNIX socket
Server type: MariaDB
Server connection: SSL is not being used Documentation
Server version: 10.3.16-MariaDB - MariaDB Server
Protocol version: 10
Server charset: UTF-8 Unicode (utf8)

Comment: See [this example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.3&fiddle=826ee6e3f0e03dd255b0a4573778f528) (click the Run button after the page loads, output is on the right-hand side of the page for each query). I've added the `DEFAULT` to `path` instead of `category_name`, but the idea would be the same

Comment: thank you so much, God bless you, this worked thank you again

Comment: @PaulT. hi can you please help with this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66977481/1146-the-table-id16202014-shoot-config-does-not-exist?noredirect=1#comment118392707_66977481)